# No module named "backport.configparser"

Tags: python, configparser, python-packaging

I have installed configparser using "pip install configparser" to get configparser-3.5.0, and is on my PYTHONPATH. But when i use it as "import configparser", i am seeing an error "No module named backports.configparser". conigparser.py use this 'backports' module and I see the 'backports' module under the python path but somehow it is unable to identify that module. Can someone give me an idea about how shall i fix this? This certainly looks to me some version problem of configparser, but I did not find any answers so far. Help will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce in a fresh python2 virtualenv with `pip install configparser`

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I have python 2.7.6 and getting that. Do you suggest any thing to get rid of that, may be upgrade configparser?

Comment: Do you actually need the python3 features?  In python2 `ConfigParser` is a stdlib module (renamed to `configparser` in python3)

Comment: not really i need python3 features, but i just did pip install configparser and i got configparser that what i have. I just need to use couple of functions from configparser. How can i get ConfigParser instead of configparser?

Comment: I was able to fix it by installing pip install configparser==3.3.0.post2, thanks for the input

Comment: `ConfigParser` is part of the stdlib in python2, just `import ConfigParser` where you were importing `configparser` (note that it won't have the new python3 features as the backport will)

Comment: @Anthony Sottile, python2 (no virtualenv, no conda) notebook ... -> `entrypoints.py`: `if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
    import configparser
else:
    from backports import configparser`

Answer (score 5):

I was able to fix it by using:

```
pip install configparser==3.3.0.post2
```

Comment: Thanks -- do you have any further information on how you arrived at this solution?

Comment: i guess by trying minor versions from https://pypi.org/project/configparser/#history

Answer (score 2):

If you are using anaconda, install configparser can solve the issue.

```
conda install -c anaconda configparser
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /Users/kaituo/anaconda2

  added / updated specs:
    - configparser


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    conda-4.5.4                |           py27_0         1.0 MB  anaconda
    configparser-3.5.0         |   py27hc7edf1b_0          35 KB  anaconda
    certifi-2018.4.16          |           py27_0         142 KB  anaconda
    openssl-1.0.2o             |       h26aff7b_0         3.4 MB  anaconda
    ca-certificates-2018.03.07 |                0         124 KB  anaconda
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         4.7 MB

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    ca-certificates: 2018.03.07-0         --> 2018.03.07-0         anaconda
    certifi:         2018.4.16-py27_0     --> 2018.4.16-py27_0     anaconda
    conda:           4.5.4-py27_0         --> 4.5.4-py27_0         anaconda
    configparser:    3.5.0-py27hc7edf1b_0 --> 3.5.0-py27hc7edf1b_0 anaconda
    openssl:         1.0.2o-h26aff7b_0    --> 1.0.2o-h26aff7b_0    anaconda

Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
conda-4.5.4          |  1.0 MB | ########################################################################################################################################### | 100%
configparser-3.5.0   |   35 KB | ########################################################################################################################################### | 100%
certifi-2018.4.16    |  142 KB | ########################################################################################################################################### | 100%
openssl-1.0.2o       |  3.4 MB | ########################################################################################################################################### | 100%
ca-certificates-2018 |  124 KB | ########################################################################################################################################### | 100%
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well today with python-2.7.6.

I fixed it by creating an empty `__init__.py` in the `<install_location>/configparser/backports` directory.

The pip install did not create it.

We had another version installed by setup.py in a different location which did have the `__init__.py` file.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case none of the solutions above work.

The easiest and probably the most reliable one would be to install `backports.configparser` directly from the source.

See: https://github.com/jaraco/configparser

You can do so by performing;

```
python setup.py install
```

**Note that**: Doing so means that you will be installing one of the latest released version. If your work demands you to use a specific version then you'll have to `checkout` the right version before installing.